# why my image generated with php is generated once, called by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a little game, i don't understand why my picture is not refreshed.
When i click on my picture, this changes state to another one and picture is refreshed. But it only works once. When i click another one time, the refresh doesn't work.
I can see the http query in my ssl_access.log of my apache server once. I click and there's not another http query.

For the click capture, i use jquery, and for the generated picture, it's php who's doing the job. I am used to php and script is good. But ... ??

The generated code is :

(html)

```
<td>
<div id="df6a055">
<img src="getImage.php?id=f6a055" id="if6a055">
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div id="df76601">
<img src="getImage.php?id=f76601" id="if76601">
</div>
</td>
....
```

(jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function () {  

$('#if6a055').on('click', function () {
$('#df6a055').html('<img src="getImage.php?j=query&id=f6a055&randval='+ Math.random() + '" id="if6a055">');
});

$('#if76601').on('click', function () {
$('#df76601').html('<img src="getImage.php?j=query&id=f76601&randval='+ Math.random() + '" id="if76601">');
});

...
```

Php objects generated are stored in a php array $_SESSION to be get by all php scripts.

I tried to use a math.random put it wasn't necessary... doesn't work.

What can i change in this jquery query to call a processed picture at the infinite ?

Thanks a lot for your interest  :)

Comment: [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) would be a solution if you want to stick to your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the problem is clear: You attach event handler to an html element that is replaced so handlers get lost.

It's not clear why you replace the entire `img` element instead of just changing the `src` property, that would be my take here.

```
$('#if6a055').on('click', function () {
    this.src = 'getImage.php?j=query&id=f6a055&randval='+ Math.random();
});
```

Comment: with your explain, it's a child's game !
It works, you're a boss !!

I've changed to
    $this->jqueryReloadPic .= "    
     $('#i" . $this->plateau [$x] [$y]->getId () . "').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop('src','getImage.php?j=query&id=" . $this->plateau [$x] [$y]->getId () . "&randval='+ Math.random());
    })
          ";
that's generated this, like you says :
    $('#i99d5c2').on('click', function () {
        $(this).prop('src','getImage.php?j=query&id=99d5c2&randval='+ Math.random());
    })

great !
thanks !